# Why was Han so sure the Millennium Falcon wasn't being tracked?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, millennium-falcon, han-solo

In the original Star Wars, the *Millennium Falcon* escapes because Darth Vader convinces Grand Moff Tarkin to allow it. The ultimate strategy is to track the ship to the Rebel Base.

> TARKIN: You're sure the homing beacon is secure aboard their ship? I'm taking an awful risk, Vader.

Shortly thereafter, Princess Leia suggests they're being tracked, and Han is his usual cocky self in responding:

> LEIA: They let us go. It's the only explanation for the ease of our escape.
>
> HAN: Easy? You call that easy?
>
> LEIA: They're tracking us.
>
> HAN: Not this ship, sister.

Obviously Han is wrong, but **why is he so sure he's safe from being tracked?**

Why would the ship make any difference to the Empire's ability to attach a homing beacon?

In *Episode II: Attack of the Clones*, we see how easy it is for Obi-Wan to attach a tracking device to Jango Fett's ship. He simply throws a disc at the ship, and it sticks to the outer hull.

**As a smuggler, shouldn't Han know about the technology behind "attachable" tracking devices?**

Comment: I think Solo is just cocky.

Comment: Also begs the question if Leia was so sure they were being tracked, why not go to some other planet an switch ships before going back to Yavin?

Comment: He got cocky, kid.

Comment: In my opinion he was just being him. Proud and confident of his ship and too stubborn to agree with others. for Skooba question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/why-is-leia-okay-with-being-tracked-to-yavin

Comment: @Skooba: That's a great question, but you're not the first. [Original HISHE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzoeEdW-EDQ) and [Special Edition HISHE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXUJiHut7YE).

Comment: @Loki your comment seems pretty popular. want to turn it into an answer so I can "accept" it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo was one of the best smugglers in the galaxy far far away and was quite cocky, not believing he could be tracked.

The are several quotes from the original trilogy that show Solo was cocky:

> Han Solo: Look, Your Worshipfulness, let's get one thing straight. I take orders from just one person: me.
>
> Princess Leia Organa: It's a wonder you're still alive.

Also,

> Han Solo: Han Solo. I'm captain of the Millennium Falcon. Chewie here tells me you're lookin' for passage to the Alderaan system?
>
> Ben Obi-Wan Kenobi: Yes indeed, if it's a fast ship.
>
> Han Solo: Fast ship? You've never heard of the Millennium Falcon?
>
> Ben Obi-Wan Kenobi: Should I have?
>
> Han Solo: It's the ship that made the Kessel Run in less than twelve parsecs. I've outrun Imperial starships. Not the local bulk cruisers mind you, I'm talking about the big Corellian ships now. She's fast enough for you old man.

and

> Leia: “I like nice men.”
> Solo: “I'm nice men.”

again to Leia:

> “I think you just can't bear to let a gorgeous guy like me out of your sight.”

and again to Leia:

> “Why are you following me? Afraid I was gonna leave without giving you a goodbye kiss?”

Comment: @Skooba I've added in several quotes that demonstrate his cockiness. Is it better now?