# Why weren't the Death Star plans transmitted electronically?

Tags: star-wars

So in the opening scene of Star War Episode IV, Darth Vader and crew are closing in on Princess Leia's ship and she puts the Death Star plans on R2-D2 and jettisons him down to Tatooine.

This seems really risky because if anything happens to the escape pod or those droids, poof, the plans are gone.

In the Star Wars canon, was there no way to electronically transmit the plans? Couldn't she have sent them to the rebel base through electronic transfer of some sort? Or, if the concern was that the Imperial fleet would detect such a transmission, couldn't she instruct R2-D2 to make such a transmission once he touched down on Tatooine?

Is there an in-universe explanation for this choice?

Comment: *VADER: Don't play games with me, Your Highness. You weren't on any mercy mission this time. You passed directly through a restricted system. **Several transmissions were beamed to this ship by Rebel spies**. I want to know what happened to the plans they sent you.* I would assume Vader ordered some sort of jamming technology instituted once the original 'beaming' transfers were discovered. It's not like they didn't use similar methods elsewhere.

Comment: In real life, data that's very large or very sensitive (and the complete Death Star plans are definitely both!) is often carried in physical media, a practice informally called "sneakernet".

Comment: More specifically, you apparently saw the beaming of the plans in Rogue One.

Comment: "Never underestimate the bandwidth of a station wagon full of tapes hurtling down the highway."

Comment: Princess Leia would have required access to the Holonet in order to transmit the plans to the Rebel base. See this question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6415/is-there-faster-than-light-communication-in-the-star-wars-universe-other-than-h

Comment: R2D2 was just a big ambulatory flash drive, after all..

Comment: @RonJohn see also [Amazon Snowball](https://www.geekwire.com/2016/use-amazons-snowball-snowballs-unleashes-45-foot-truck-model/)

Comment: @Spencer: Complete with flashy lights and whirring sounds.

Comment: @A.C. Also [this](https://what-if.xkcd.com/31/).

Comment: @Cadence, though sensitivity is hardly an issue here, the rebels probably wouldn't care less if the plans were broadcast to every single sentient entity in the galaxy. It would even be good for them, as there would be no single recipient for the Empire to go after.

Comment: @ilkkachu You might very well think that until [some criminal lunatics build a superweapon of their own based on the Death Star plans](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darksaber_(superweapon)). When you give it to every sentient, you give it to *every sentient*, no exceptions.

Comment: The Death Star plans were transmitted electronically - at the end of Rogue One (prequel to A New Hope); that is how Leia obtained them in the first place. They just took a different form (stored in R2D2) from that point forward. Out-of-universe, nobody thought of transmitting complex documents back in the 1970s. It's only our better informed perspective in an internet-enabled cellphone-carrying world that we can think of exchanging documents over-the-air, perhaps why it shows up in the much more recently written Rogue One.

Comment: ... again, out-of-universe, 1970s audiences might not have related as easily to plans transmitted from A to B as they did to plans carried in a physical object, or stored in a robot (R2D2). And again, from a story writing perspective, R2D2 and the plans become something of a [MacGuffin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGuffin)... more or less.

Comment: @AnthonyX Out-of-universe, no. Darth Vader talks about the plans being received as transmissions in A New Hope. But who would they transmit it to while having a star destroyer in pursuit? Their communications were completely jammed, and even if they weren't, they would be intercepted - highlighting both the weakness in design (imagine the final battle if they actually scrambled TIEs to intercept!) and the location of the rebel base. The Empire controls the Hypernet, and everything else is too slow. Sending it on R2D2 to Obi-wan was a last resort thing.

Comment: Vader: "I find your lack of bandwidth disturbing."

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Transmissions were sent, but the reason they relied on the physical transfer of the plans was because transmissions can be traced, and blocked, or intercepted. As [Jeeped](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/62584/jeeped) provided in a comment:

> *VADER: Don't play games with me, Your Highness. You weren't on any mercy mission this time. You passed directly through a restricted system. **Several transmissions were beamed to this ship by Rebel spies.** I want to know what happened to the plans they sent you.* I would assume Vader ordered some sort of jamming technology instituted once the original 'beaming' transfers were discovered. It's not like they didn't use similar methods elsewhere.

Vader knew the rebels were attempting to get their hands on the plans, because of the previous attempts to transmit them. The reason why he was interrogating Leia was because he knew that the droids had escaped with the plans - and physical objects can be harder to track.

> R2-D2 and C-3PO used an escape pod to smuggle the Death Star plans off the Tantive IV. The Devastator's officers noticed, but neglected to fire as they detected no lifeforms aboard.

[Source](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Escape_pod)

Comment: Thanks @Ben. I think I worded my question poorly as what I'm more interested in is why didn't the Rebels disseminate the Death Star plans far and wide? I mean, today, if a terrorist unearthed secret information that would be injurious to the state they are trying to topple, they'd not try to keep it hidden but would rather publish it online and spread the news far and wide, no? But this is a great answer for the question I asked.

Comment: *The Devastator's officers noticed, neglected to fire as they detected no lifeforms aboard.* I'd think that in a universe where droids are commonplace, this demonstrates a serious lapse in judgement on their part.  Heck, even without the existence of droids, any package leaving a ship suspected to be carrying valuable contraband should be at least tracked if not retrieved and/or destroyed.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Maybe it's the sci-fi equivalent of the "eh, not my job" attitude.

Comment: "they'd not try to keep it hidden but would rather publish it online and spread the news far and wide, no?" Depends what the information is. You would only try to spread information that reveals how your enemy can be attacked if you can't perform the attack yourself; otherwise someone may protect the enemy (in this case someone not on Death Star project may point out flaw Rebels used to attack the Death Star such that it gets fixed before Rebels can exploit it).

Comment: @Darrel: not firing on the escape pod may be typical bureaucracy. maybe in the previous month somebody got in trouble for wasting ammo by laying waste to everything in sight, so a memo got sent out telling everybody not to fire unless they detected life, and now everybody is steadfastly following the rule even though it doesn't make any sense. in any bureaucracy bungling and incompetence are rife.

Comment: @NathanHughes If they were that concerned about wasting ammo, you'd think they'd train their storm troopers how to shoot properly...

Comment: @ScottMitchell Because the plans may have revealed a vulnerability that was an error, and could easily be fixed.  **Think of the vulnerability like a zero-day exploit**; if you widely publish it, a lot of eyes get put on it, somebody goes "hey, did you know there's a ..." And then it's a foot-race between the rebels exploiting it and the Empire fixing it, [which is non-trivial in an Imperial bureaucracy.](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=nsJpTTIEySo)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman The only time we see stormtroopers consistently miss their targets is when they're herding Skywalker et al off the Death Star and back to their ship, which has been implanted with a tracker so that they can find the rebel base.

Comment: @Harper - weren’t the plans already in the possession of the Imperial army? And didn’t they already know there was a potential vulnerability? I mean, the whole thing from acquiring the plans to destroying the Death Star took what, a few days in total? But everything was risked by Leia sending them with the droids. I would think she’d want to disseminate them so the rebels could launch an immediate attack rather than waiting and hoping the plans weren’t lost.

Comment: @ScottMitchell there's a difference between "the Empire having the plans" and "everyone having the plans", just as there's a difference between "Microsoft having the source code" vs "everyone". The difference is the number of eyes looking at that code, and is extremely large.

Comment: @ScottMitchell The empire did not know about the vulnerability (which, depending on your own canon, was a deliberate design feature hidden from the Imperial administrators). This may contradict with Vader's knowledge that plans were transmitted but perhaps the transmitted plans wasn't detailed enough to highlight the flaw or maybe didn't even contain the flaw. What we know for certain is that the copy of the plan on physical media clearly shows the flaw

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: A real-world example: a colleague of mine told me a story about one of his former employers. Because they were working with very valuable equipment in a poor country (a TV studio in Africa), guards were instructed to check the trunk of every car leaving the garage. One day, he had brought a broken VCR from home which he intended to drop off for repair at the shop after work. Even though this was clearly a consumer device, and clearly broken, they wouldn't let him leave. They took their assignment, to check the trunk of every car, very seriously. You could, however, take out a …

Comment: … 300000$ piece of equipment out on your backseat without any hassle. Like I said, they took their assignment to check *the trunk* of every car *very* seriously. Maybe, the officers were instructed to prevent any passenger from leaving, and according to Galactic Empire Customs Rulebook #5783, article 467, paragraph 573, clause 345,III,b) droids are considered cargo, not passengers.

Comment: At a point like this, i just say "they did it because it was in the script, to drive the plot forward"

Comment: @ScottMitchell They also had a vital piece of information that *wasn't* in the original plans - but would have been added to the stolen copy (assuming Rogue One happened). After all, the original plans didn't say "HERE! Shoot a torpedo here and everything blows up!". But just as importantly, the Rebels are terrorists, yes - but they (especially Leia's faction) don't want to watch the world burn. There's plenty of people out there who could build a superlaser of their own. You don't want to send them detailed plans of how to do that.

Comment: @ScottMitchell according to Rogue One the original Library which housed the presumably only copy of the plans was destroyed by Tarkin. If they had this super-safe archive, which was only accessible by physically going down there, I assume they will not have a copy of this top-secret information laying around somewhere else. - So the rebels have probably the only copy of the original plans left in the galaxy...

Comment: @Falco So, the Empire stole them back at some point before RotJ?

Comment: @Luaan To that, in *Rogue One*, Galen tells Jyn there's a flaw and that it's hidden. He tells her what it is and where to look for it, which she tells the Rebels before heisting the plans. Presumably, only knowing "there is a flaw" would not be enough to find it in a timely fashion, and evidently countless engineers worked on the Death Star project for years not noticing it ever existed.

Comment: @AmiralPatate Exactly. I can imagine some engineers have noticed, but either kept  it to themselves (if they didn't particularly like the Empire), or reported it to Galen and got reassigned, or had an accident or something. Planet shattering superweapons are serious stuff.

Comment: @Chronocidal From the perspective of the Rebels the existence of the second Death Star came as a complete shock. Up until the battle they believed it could not be operational in such a short time - which would fall in line with the Rebels believing that the stolen plans where vital to the Imperium and should not fall into their hands. - As for speculation, maybe the Imperium got their hands on the plans after the battle of Hoth and extracted the details for the inner workings, which they needed to make DS2 functional?

Comment: @ScottMitchell on the possibility that the Rebels could widespread the Death Star plans, so they could not be destroyed. All mainstream communications (including Holonet) were maintained by the Empire, so it would be pointless to do so.

Answer (score 26):

## Interstellar transmissions are low-bandwidth, and they degrade easily.

The Death Star is an enormous engineering project.  Its blueprints fit into a physically small volume, but so does C-3PO's vast linguistics database; the amount of data in the Death Star plans must be astonishing.  The Rebels hope to find a way to exploit Galen Erso's sabotage, but they don't know where in the plans to look for vulnerabilities,<sup>(1)</sup> so they need to send the entire set.

With Imperial forces in hot pursuit, the rebels didn't have time to transmit the data with enough redundancy to protect against signal degradation and ensure the plans' reception in usable form.  For example, asteroids interfere with interstellar transmissions:<sup>(2)</sup>

> **PIETT:** The Emperor commands you [to] make contact with him.
>
> **VADER:** Move the ship out of the asteroid field so that we can send a clear transmission.
>
> — [*The Empire Strikes Back*](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Empire-Strikes-Back.html)

These lines of dialogue begin at 0:24 in this clip, followed by a flickering, jittery, grainy projection from the most powerful person in the Empire:

Since the Emperor — with all of his resources — can't send a steady, detailed faster-than-light transmission, the rebels must have faced even greater limitations.

Vader's conference with the low-resolution, flickering images of the ship captains at the start of the clip takes place in realtime, with no speed-of-light lag.  Although at least some of the ships are close enough together for lightspeed communication, the simplest explanation is that they are using the same faster-than-light communication system here that they would use at interstellar distances.

A similar effect appears about 79 minutes into *The Phantom Menace*.  While on Tatooine, Padme uses her royal yacht's holographic communicator to play a message from Sio Bibble on Naboo.  Bibble's low-resolution image constantly wavers, and his voice is distorted.  Even the most stable frames in his message are blocky:

[image: Sio Bibble hologram]

Darth Sidious' holograms in *The Phantom Menace* show the same characteristic jitter and pixellation.  He was concealing his identity throughout this film, though, so the poor image quality in this case *may* be due to more than technological limitations:

---

<sup>(1)</sup> The attack plan that the Rebels hurriedly devised in *Episode IV* depended on Galen Erso's sabotage and on two design flaws (the shield permeability and the exhaust port), and ultimately it only succeeded because of space wizards.  The Rebels may have been able to devise a safer and more reliable attack strategy if they'd had more time to study the Death Star plans.

<sup>(2)</sup> The fleet's use of weapons may be a contributing factor, but if it was the only concern then the ship would not have had to *leave* the asteroid field.

Comment: So nobody in the history of this galaxy-wide tens-of-thousands of years old civilization has ever come up with fault-tolerant bitwise error checking? Geez! Humans figured that out in the early 1960's before the internet even existed.

Comment: @RichS It's a strange place, that galaxy. [One theory](https://www.tor.com/2012/10/03/most-citizens-of-the-star-wars-galaxy-are-probably-totally-illiterate/) has it that there's been little in the way of developing writing, or at least widespread literacy.

Comment: @RichS Maybe they do have error checking and just don't use it for video since it's fault tolerant. We often use [lossy protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) for video for that reason. And with the amount of static in the videos we see here, if they retransmitted every packet with detected errors, they'd need to retransmit...I'm going to say all of them. Several times each. Error checking increases bandwidth requirements.

Comment: @RichS, and who says they aren't using it? :) Error correction requires more data to transfer, and if that's the best they can get even with it, then, well. Then again, one could ask why they bother with video instead of audio only...

Comment: @Ray Using lossy protocols is okay for video and audio streaming, but if you want to send details schematics, then you probably want a verbatim transmission protocol. Which invalidates the entire point of Gaultheria's answer because all of the examples are video-audio transmissions.

Comment: @RichS It doesn't invalidate Gaultheria's answer, because the point still stands - interstellar transmissions are very limited. They are extremely fast, yes, but the bandwidth is lacking. You could send the plans using the Holonet, but it would take a long time. They didn't have any time :) Also, Holonet is controlled by the Empire, and any message can be easily stolen, traced and blocked. They would send the information about the weakness, and it wouldn't reach its destination (Tantive was being jammed even before starting its escape attempt), while it would be intercepted by the Empire.

Comment: @RichS Perhaps the Rebels didn't want a 4-hour transmission pointing directly at their hidden base?  I would imagine that short-range transmission from the Archive to the Ships had a far higher bandwidth, but they still had to wait for it to transfer...

Answer (score 14):

The end goal for the Death Star plans was to send them to the hidden rebel base at Yavin IV, to be analyzed for any possible weakness to destroy the Death Star.

It seems obvious why they wouldn't want to transfer the plans directly to that base - it's a *hidden* rebel base. Any transfer to that location, if intercepted, would immediately reveal the base's location.

And we know the Empire can track transmissions like this.

> VADER: Don't play games with me, Your Highness. You weren't on any mercy mission this time. You passed directly through a restricted system. Several transmissions were beamed to this ship by Rebel spies. I want to know what happened to the plans they sent you.

If they caught wind of the plans being transmitted to a random moon near the planet Yavin, it would immediately clue the Empire in on their location.

As it turns out, the Empire discovered the location anyway.  But they had no way of knowing that would happen when making these plans.

Comment: Also, when you're trying to plan something big, you can't rely on every single thing going right. You're planning in a way that allows you to work around problems that develop.

Answer (score 0):

How?

In the Star Wars universe, long-distance communication is not good or reliable - image quality on links is well below what you'd accept for Skype, and keeps dropping in and out.  Getting large files over that kind of link simply isn't practical.

Sure, a broadcast might get the message spread around. But how do you know anyone is listening?

Answer (score 0):

### Because it was most likely the last copy in the Galaxy

At the end of Rogue One Tarkin destroyed the whole library, which housed the original copy of the death star plans. The plans were ridiculously well protected at this place, one had to physically access a tape and extract the data from it. So it is very likely that this was the only copy of the top secret information. Otherwise the Rebels would probably have tried to steal it from a less protected place and Crennic would not have to go there in person to access the data.

Even if we cannot say for sure if the disk was in fact the last copy of the Death Star plans, the Rebels would have reason to strongly believe so. If the Imperium did not have the original plans anymore, it would have been a lot harder to re-engineer some of the finer details of the machine to find the weakness themselves. And it would probably be harder for the Imperium or anyone else to build a new Death Star or improve on the original design without the original plans.

### Transmissions can be blocked, traced and captured

Different scenes from the movies and series suggest that transmissions in Star Wars can be blocked by interference. They can also be traced (as it seems origin and even destination can sometimes be traced by the enemy) - this would endanger all involved parties and the transmission might not even go through (especially with the huge amounts of data the plans contained)

Also canon suggests that almost all forms of encryption can be hacked in the Star Wars Universe. This would mean that any transmission over wider range would pose the risk of the empire or someone else capturing the plans. This is a huge risk, since the empire would then specifically know what details the rebels have in possession, could search and fix the weakness and could (probably) more easily build a new death star or improve the current one.

An agent carrying a disk could probably destroy it before being captured.

Answer (score -1):

The simple asnwer would be,security and demand for such data/schematics
Considering the paperless trail and origins of delivery.

Comment: Of course this is already covered in some of the existing answers and with evidence that this sort of thing could be tracked in the Star Wars universe.

Answer (score -1):

As we know now, princess Leia had two missions. First mission is to retrieve the Death Star plans and the second was  to find Obi-Wan Kenobi and bring him to the alliance. The transmitting the plans was out of the question. As her father said he trusted her with his own life to get the job done.